# How likely are flares to be fire hazards once touching the ground?

Tags: military

According to the Wikipedia page of flares, flares create intense heat.

> A flare, also sometimes called a fusee, is a type of pyrotechnic that produces a brilliant light or intense heat without an explosion.

Could the flares launched by an aircraft as a defensive countermeasure against a heat-seeking missile cause a fire once they reach the ground?

Comment: Any pryotechnic released close enough to combustable materials will combust, I'm not sure what the question is? Are you asking if the flares are flame-resistant? Are you asking if they are designed to extinguish before hitting the ground? Are you asking from what altitude they can be released without touching the ground in a combusting state?

Comment: I'm wondering if the event of a fire starting on ground due to flares launched from above (Likely due to flammable terrain such as a forest) has already happened.

Comment: Not really an aviation question....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea how likely it is general, but it seems that flares are indeed sometimes blamed for causing wildfires on the ground.

[In New Jersey (2007)](http://blog.nj.com/ledgerupdates/2007/05/flare_from_fighter_jet_blamed.html):

> A massive wildfire that has already burned thousands of acres in the
>   Pinelands and forced the evacuation of residents in two towns likely
>   started this afternoon when an F-16 fighter jet dropped flares as part
>   of a maneuver over a gunnery range, New Jersey National Guard
>   officials said tonight.
>
> [...]
>
> "We believe it was one of our F-16s on a routine training mission that
>   dropped the flare that started the fire," said Lt. Col. James Garcia,
>   a spokesman for the state Department of Military and Veterans Affairs.
>   "There's going to be an investigation."

[In Oregon (2017)](https://www.opb.org/news/series/wildfires/feds-examine-military-flares-in-mysterious-oregon-wildfires/):

> A remnant of a military flare was found at one of the areas burned,
>   triggering a call to the Air National Guard, which uses flares in
>   self-defense training exercises over those same areas that burned.
>   Flares are deployed in air combat to draw heat-seeking missiles away
>   from their targets.
>
> After being contacted by investigators about the fires, the Oregon
>   National Guard agreed to suspend the use of flares. Agencies also
>   engaged them about mitigation techniques to employ if it is determined
>   that the guard was the cause.